# htaccess redirect if URI contains string to index.php

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I would like to redirect link http://example.com/asdasdas/edit to http://example.com/asdasdas/index.php/edit using htaccess. I did this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} edit
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}/index.php [L,R=301]
```

but it's a loop and doesn't works well. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule in `/asdasdas/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /asdasdas/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.+) index.php/$ [L]
```

This will support URL of `http://example.com/asdasdas/edit`